# How to insert values in a quoted vector

Tags: clojure

I have a function

```
(defn hi [a] '[a 2])
```

which should take a value a and insert the value in a quoted vector, and return the vector back.

So calling `(hi :abc)` should return `[:abc 2]`.
 The important thing to note is that the internal vector is quoted.
 How do I do this?

Comment: Why is the internal vector quoted?

Comment: because it has symbols which are not valid data in clojure ex - ?ab. It is datomic query structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to pass an undefined symbol to the function, and get back a vector containing that symbol (with some other stuff added).

If you quote the symbol before passing it to the function, then you don't have to do anything special inside the function:

```
user=> (defn hi [a] [a 2])
user=> (= (hi '?ab) '[?ab 2])
true
```

If you don't want to quote your symbols (e.g. you're making a DSL to enable idiomatic authoring of datomic query structures) then you have to use a macro, because eval'ing a function will cause the symbol to be resolved in the namespace. You could try something like:

```
user=> (defmacro hi2 [a] `(quote [~a 2]))
user=> (= (hi2 ?ab) '[?ab 2])
true
```

Answer (score 1):

This can help:

```
user=> (defn hi [a] [a '2])
#'user/hi
user=> (hi :abc)
[:abc 2]
```